# C++/MFC. Insert Image in CSV file Using MFC

Tags: c++, image, csv, mfc

Hello I'm studying MFC and I wanna know how to insert some images un csv file.

The file structure is as follows:The result folder contains 1.jpg, 2.jpg files.

In csv file, at the top "Index, Name, Age, Picture" must be included and "Index, Name, Age" are in the List Control.
I've finished entering the information in the csv file using the code below. However, I can't figure out how to insert the images in csv file.
`

```
    CString _FilePath = theApp.m_ResultDir + _T("Result.csv");  //m_ResultDir : result folder Location
    std::ofstream File(_FilePath,'w');
    File << "Index, Name, Age, Picture\n";
    CHeaderCtrl* pHeader = (CHeaderCtrl*)m_ListControl.GetHeaderCtrl();
    int nRow = m_ListControl.GetItemCount();
    int nCol = pHeader->GetItemCount();

    CString text;

    for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++)
    {
        text = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++)
        {
            text = text+ m_ListControl.GetItemText(i, j) + _T(", ");
        }

        File << text + "\n";
    }
    File.close();
```

`

It would be easy problem, but I'd appreciate it if you understand because it's my first time doing this.

This are what I tried.

First, I tried using TypeLib and select excel.exe and i contained some header files. However, I wanna make it csv file not xlsx file.

Second, using result folder location, I tried to add images. but failed.
`

```
        CString image;
        image.Format(theApp.m_ResultDir+_T("%d.jpg"), i+1);
        text += image;
```

`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? CSV is a textual format, it can't contain (embedded) images, if you mean that. It can contain image filenames though. So your set of data will be the CSV file along with the image files, in the same folder or in a subfolder, for example File0232.csv and File0232\img0001.jpg, File0232\img0002.jpg, File0232\img0003.jpg etc.

Comment: I think it is necessary here to cast CString in LPCTSTR to extract in std::ofstream. 'File << text.GetString()'

Answer (score 0):

First argument to `CString::Format` is a format specification, followed by the arguments to be formatted. So something like that would work:

```
image.Format(_T("%s%d.jpg"), theApp.m_ResultDir, i+1);
```